# Firebase messaging token comes with installation id in android

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, azure-notificationhub

is anyone getting this format of token from firebase,

Refreshed token: dS2caa8JTpi6S6BSsvjAsv:APA91bFK10hW36vZ6qKgFV5vSS2Hx91vZfSsrBvGTxF2K3q76Gx6QHve3wYOk6-8zAIzGvQiYfEgkkc--0ZUILPPY60PdVurIis7DVsuGB3C6XArzsMUAE3zZJY-KFb3h-cDWQxc0zLX

it comes with firebaseInstallationID+":"+RefreshToken (to send push notification) and this format is not accepted by Azure Notification hub.

Comment: _Not accepted means?_  how did you come to know.

Comment: notification failed with this error - "the token is invalid from the token provider"

Comment: Have you added API key to your ANH? Also have you test notification using your fcm token to your device? Are you able to get notification it??

Comment: I tried - sending notification from console - it works
and without this part "dS2caa8JTpi6S6BSsvjAsv:" (fid) firebase also show error 
so the token is correct but with fid it's not accepting in ANH.

Comment: So your token is valid

Comment: yes, lemme share error i'm getting from api when i try to save token using api

Comment: okay share it..

Comment: The path 'sb://mm…” fIkZKbN_R4W6-3RkLao19k:APA91bFiptwkHgH4Bpa8ZxXbTGZZf2tH5xQIMCBeXw4styLf47F1Ah-LYtodaD6CfDmVq8FuMpk5ySrC7x04KnfsuMD4ifdepN-Os4weiCtDpAGHaoolDgsO_-hX7L3ys1gDA9nAXMDe?api-version=2020-06' contains character(s) that are not allowed by Service Bus. Entity segments can contain only letters, numbers, periods (.), hyphens (-), and underscores (_)..TrackingId:9f783da3-b5f8-455d-b002-12387f076849_G3,

Comment: do you have any idea for this issue?

Comment: _'sb://mm…” fIkZKbN_R4W6-3RkLao19k:APA91bFiptwkHgH4Bpa8ZxXbTGZZf2tH5xQIMCBeXw4styLf47F1Ah-LYtodaD6CfDmVq8FuMpk5ySrC7x04KnfsuMD4ifdepN-Os4weiCtDpAGHaoolDgsO_-hX7L3ys1gDA9nAXMDe?api-version=2020-06'_ this path is from ANH?

Comment: yeah , saving the token on ANH

Comment: https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs-dotnet/issues/48

Comment: I'm sending this as token from firebase to receive push notification, but it's not validating on ANH.